# CSS Transformation

Tags: css, math, transform, linear-algebra

how can I change with CSS (-moz-transform) a div that should look like this:
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can take a look at the [Mozilla Developer Center](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/-moz-transform). There even are examples.

However, it looks to me like your specific example isn't possible (yet):

> **Note:** At this time, the Z axis is not supported, so perspective, 3D rotation, 3D scaling, and 3D transformations are not supported. —[Using CSS transforms](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/Using_CSS_transforms)

You can't recreate this effect with only skewing, rotation and translation in a plane. Parallel lines will always be parallel, even after the transformation.

Comment: I think the question is about the matrix that should be used, which is math problem